# javascript code from DB

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a field in the database that contain a big javascript code. How can I add this code to view ?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // javascript code from DB in a RaphaelObject property
   "@Model.RaphaelObject";
  });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `@Html.Raw(Model.RaphaelObject)`

Answer (score 2):

remove quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // javascript code from DB in a RaphaelObject property
    @Model.RaphaelObject
});
```

May be you have encoded the js code string. so maybe **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.RaphaelObject)** is needed.